# How can I use dockpanel in Linux/Mono with all its features?

Tags: linux, mono, dockpanel-suite

I would like to use dockpanel suite in Linux or Mono platform. I heard that there is some methods to modify the source code of dockpanel so that it can be used in Linux platform with all its features like drag and drop and all.Can anyone guide me to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Due to its close bindings to Win32 API/PInvoke, currently it is impossible to use full features on Mono. You probably misinterpreted others' words.

Edited: DockPanel Suite 2.6 and above contains Mono support that I developed, http://dockpanelsuite.com

Comment: Thanks for this - how do I "turn off" the advanced features (i.e. those which use P/Invoke or Kernel32 etc) so I can compile it and run it in Mono on Linux?

Comment: If you use DPS 2.6 and above, the incompatible features are automatically disabled at runtime. You don't need to do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.. You can write a silverlight 4.0 program and run it in a browser window on linux you can use silverlight controls.

If you are feeling really brave you can use MoonLight (silverlight by mono) to write full desktop apps on linux. One helpful set of tools (shameless plug) for doing this is [**MoonBase**](https://github.com/inorton/MoonBase)

But.. Generally, No, if you mean the WPF DockPanel control, you can't use that on top of Mono.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've used WPF tag, but what you heard indicates rather winforms. In such case you may be interested in [this](http://www.lextm.com/2010/05/dockpanel-suite-tip-4-we-could-go-mono.html). If you really had WPF in mind, look at the IanNorton's answer.